# Error when getting value from constant : Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: swift, swift3

I am using `enum` and `tuple` with value of enum case. I've trouble with getting value from [String: String] constant.

I don't know how to fix it, it has to be a trap, but I don't know where, as the `key` is surely string:

```
enum DictTypes : String {
        case settings
        case options
        case locations
    }
    enum FileTypes : String {
        case json
        case pList
    }

    func getCodebookUrlComponent() -> String
    {
        var FileSpecs: (
                dictType: DictTypes,
                fileType: FileTypes,
                redownload: Bool
            ) = (.settings, .json, true)

        let codebooks = [
            "settings" : "settings",
            "options" : "options"
        ]

        let key = self.FileSpecs.dictType // settings or options

        if let urlComponent = codebooks[key] {

            return urlComponent
        }

        return ""
    }
```

This line `if let urlComponent = codebooks[key]` comes with an error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.rawValue` for this case :

```
if let urlComponent = codebooks[key.rawValue]{
   return urlComponent
}
```

This problem occurs because of the  `let key = self.FileSpecs.dictType` in this line you receive key that is `FileSpecs` type. And `subscript` that is implemented in the `Array` will not conform for that value type.

`rawValue` in you're case return String value that you assign in you're `enum`.

Comment: Thank you, I would't get it

Answer (score 1):

Since value from enum case is surely string, I would type it like this:

```
let key = FileSpecs.dictType.rawValue // "settings" or "options"
```

**or**

```
let key = String(describing: FileSpecs.dictType) 

return codebooks[key]!
```